# How Do I Launch a Dialog in MFC?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc, modal-dialog

I'm fairly new to VC++ and MFC, so bear with me. I have created a new dialog, and I want to figure out how to display it when the user clicks a button.

I have not create a class or header file for the dialog -- I tried using the class wizard, but it pretty much sucked and didn't work. That, or I was doing something wrong. Either one is equally as likely if you ask me.

So what steps do I need to take when creating the source/header files and getting the dialog to launch/display? It is a modal dialog.

**CLARIFICATION:** I understand that I need to create an instance of the dialog class, then just call DoModal() on it, but I'm not sure how to create the class file (with and/or without the wizard).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Right click the project and select
   Add | Resource...
2. Select Dialog under Resource
   type and click New.
3. Select Project | Add Class...
4. Enter `CMyDialog` for the Class
   name, `CDialog` for the Base class
   and Click Finish.

Read more: [How to Make MFC Dialog Boxes](http://www.ehow.com/how_2089571_make-mfc-dialog-boxes-mfc.html)

Comment: This solved it. I had done everything you mentioned, but I didn't name my class correctly. I was trying to add in the "C" manually before my class name because I had seen it in my other dialog class files. Woops! Thanks though, Dave! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you can make the button click just create a new instance of the dialog object and activate it. You'll probably have to keep a reference to the dialog so it doesn't get killed when the button action fxn returns it doesn't get garbage collected..

Comment: I think I know how to create an instance of the dialog and call DoModal()...it's mostly the class creation that I'm unsure of.